# Abort JSONP ajax request with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp, abort

I'm using a JSONP ajax call to load some content from a different domain, and all this stuff is executed if the user causes a "mouseover" on a button.

I can capture the $.ajax() call return as a xhr object, and use it to abort the ajax request each time the user causes a "mouseover". But the JSONP callback function still gets called, and this causes an error, and I think it is beacuse the xhr.abort() method does not prevent the callback function to be called.

I've tried surrounding the $.ajax() call with try{}catch(e){}, but after I call the xhr.abort() method, the error continues.

Is there a way to handle that exception?

The raised exception is like this (according to Firebug):
**jQuery16102234208755205157_1308941669256 is not a function**

And the exception's internal structure is like this:
**jQuery16102234208755205157_1308941669256({... my json data from a different domain....})**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kill ajax requests using javascript using jquery.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

Comment: I guess this is not that duplicate, because this question is about preventing an exception after the jqxhr.abort() method is called on a JSONP ajax request, not about how to stop the request itself.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found at the duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533848/aborting-jquery-jsonp-request-will-throw-error

Comment: very old question. stumbled upon the same issue today. I added my contribute. I don't know if my answer deserve to be the accepted one, but for sure the accepted one should not be the current (downvoted) one

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In jQuery 1.5 all the Ajax APIs have a wrapper object around the native XHR objects. Take a look at:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

```
 jqxhr.abort(); // should be what you're looking for
```

Comment: This is what I am using right now. This aborts the ajax request. But this ajax request uses JSONP. After I use the "abort()" method, a javascript function generated internally by jQuery to handle the JSONP response is called, but the abort method seems to remove that function definition, or something, because there is an exception that I haven't been able to handle.

Comment: Do you have any more information? live example, exception message?

Answer (score 11):

The basic answer is simply the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533901/66226): You can't really `abort()` a JSONP call. So the real question is, how do you avoid both superfluous callback invocations and the error you're seeing?

You can't use `try...catch` around the callback because it's asynchronous; you'd have to catch it from jQuery's end, and jQuery generally doesn't handle exceptions thrown from callbacks. (I discuss this in my book, [*Async JavaScript*](http://leanpub.com/asyncjs).) What you want to do instead is use a unique identifier for each Ajax call and, when the success callback is invoked, check whether that identifier is the same as it was when you made the call. Here's an easy implementation:

```
var requestCount = 0;
$.ajax(url, {
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  requestCount: ++requestCount,
  success: function(response, code) {
    if (requestCount !== this.requestCount) return;
    // if we're still here, this is the latest request...
  }
});
```

Here I'm taking advantage of the fact that anything you pass to `$.ajax` is attached to the object that's used as `this` in the callback.

It'd be nice if jQuery made `abort()` do this for us, of course.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not abort the request**

Just store somewhere the **jqXHR** object returned by `$.ajax()`

```
theJqXHR = $.ajax(....
```

If the user cancel the request null the saved object

```
// user canceled
theJqXHR = null;
```

Finally when you receive the response (`success` callback) the callback will compare the jqXHR object of the response with the saved object.

```
function successCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR )
{
    if( theJqXHR !== jqXHR )
    {
        // user canceled; discard the response
        return;
    }

    // process the response
}
```

No jQuery errors.

---

As a general advice don't rely upon `abort()`, even for regular ajax requests.

1. In any case you won't save resource on the server bacause **the request you sent will be processed and there is no way to stop it**. And a response will come back.
2. Some (older) browsers handle `abort()` not properly.

Just "*cache*" the jqXHR object and handle the *CANCEL* scenario yourself.

Comment: The third argument XHR never matches the object returned by $.ajax

Comment: @JackCole I've tried and, actually yes, **it does**. Try this on the console: `jqxhr1=$.ajax({url: "/", success: function(data,status,jqxhr2){alert(jqxhr1===jqxhr2);}})` What I get is `true`

Answer (score 1):

jsonpString overrides the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the query string in the URL.

So `{jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'}` would result in `'onJSONPLoad=?'` passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the `?callback` string to the URL or attempting to use `=?` for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the `jsonpCallback` setting. For example, `{ jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

jQuery adds `?callback=jQuery17109492628197185695_1339420031913` and later sets the request data as parameter to this callback, so you will have:

```
jQuery17109492628197185695_1339420031913({
  "status": 200,
  "data": {your json}
})
```

To avoid setting additional parameters to request a URL and calling callback, add this parameter to ajax method: `jsonp:false`, so it will be look like:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  jsonp:false,
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trevor Burnham's answer is pretty good, but instead of tracking a request count, you should just compare the request to the XHR parameter, like so;

```
doRequest: function() {
    this._freeRequest();

    this._request = $.getJSON(url + params + '&callback=?', function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (this._request !== xhr) return; // aborted

        // success
    }.bind(this)).done(this._freeRequest.bind(this));
}

_freeRequest: function() {
    if (this._request) {
        delete this._request;
    }
}
```

Calling `doRequest` again or `_freeRequest` once before the previous request has completed, will result in the "abortion" of said request by causing the `if (this._request !== xhr)` line to become true, since `this._request` will either be deleted or another request altogether.