# jQuery ajax error callback not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, callback

I am requesting a URL with ajax that results in a HTTP header code 500. I would expect this to trigger the error function:

```
    $.ajax({
  url: "http://xxx",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function( data ) {
        alert('success');
  },
  error: function () {
        alert('error');
  }
});
```

This works in safari, but fails in chrome and firefox.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the latest jquery 1.4.X, for reasons I cannot upgrade to later versions..

The response sends a HTTP code 500, content type application/json and contents:

jsonp1310063232212({"error":{"reason":"User not found"}})

Comment: I'm not sure if this version of jQuery can detect JSONP errors. Try setting a timeout to your request. The callback may be called if no result has been received after the timeout has expired.

Comment: Thanks, but no change. No error callback, no success callback. Also added ajaxError method but that too does not get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `crossDomain:` wasn't added until jQuery 1.5.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> crossDomain(added 1.5)
>
> Default: false
>   for same-domain requests, true for
>   cross-domain requests.
>
> If you wish to
>   force a crossDomain request (such as
>   JSONP) on the same domain, set the
>   value of crossDomain to true. This
>   allows, for example, server-side
>   redirection to another domain

Like Martin Larente suggested in his comment, it could be an issue with how different browsers or jQuery detects/reports JSONP errors.

Answer (score 6):

As stated on JQuery documentation [1] the error handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. It worked (not always) on older versions of JQuery.

I solve using a compact and effective plugin that include a nice error handler:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

Download it and add it to head:

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery.jsonp-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you can use function $.jsonp() similar to $.ajax():

```
$.jsonp({
    url: "http://xxx?callback=?",
    data: {
        var: 'test'
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function(xOptions, textStatus) {
        console.log('Error');
        // ...
    }
});
```

[1] http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i'm stuck using an older version of jquery (1.8.2), and switching to jsonp function worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be outstanding issues with this see. [Abort JSONP ajax request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472509/abort-jsonp-ajax-request-with-jquery)