# Aborting jQuery JSONP request will throw error

Tags: jquery, jsonp

i am making simple autosuggestion (autocompleter) plugin with jQuery. Unfortunately i have to use jsonp. It is ok and it works, but when i am aborting request it will throw error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery171036404498340561986_1330693563756' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

There is code

```
if(xhr) {xhr.abort()};
xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "someurl/getmedata",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {q: "query"},
    success: function(results) {},
    error: function() {}
})
```

Classic way with json, xml or other request works fine.

Anny suggestion?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the earlier [Abort JSONP ajax request with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472509/abort-jsonp-ajax-request-with-jquery), though that question was never properly answered and this one was.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`JSONP` does **not** use `XMLHTTPRequest` but actually creates a `<script>` tag within the document to be able to make the cross-domain requests.

You simply cannot abort JSONP requests.

It is stated in the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation:

> Some types of Ajax requests, such as **JSONP** and cross-domain GET requests, **do not use XHR**; in those cases the XMLHttpRequest and textStatus parameters passed to the callback are undefined.

As for jQuery 1.5+, previously was returning the XHR object from $.ajax(), now it returns a superset jqXHR object which encapsulates the XHR object.

> When the transport mechanism is something other than XMLHttpRequest (for example, a script tag for a JSONP request) the jqXHR object **simulates native XHR functionality where possible**.

So it returns an object but some functionnalities are actually not available, like .abort().

---

The plugin **[jQuery-JSONP](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/)** seems to offer the possibility to manually abort JSONP requests. I haven't used it myself but it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: Ok get it. Is there any other way how to handle missing function in global context?

Comment: I've added a link to the plugin [jquery-jsonp](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) which seems to offer the possiblity to abort jsonp requests.

Comment: Is it ok to use dynamic callback name? like `callback = random()`
`$.jsonp({url: "my_url?callback=" +callback, callback: callback})`

Comment: Honnestly I don't much about this plugin, I just head about it. According to [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/wiki/APIDocumentation) it seems possible yes.

Comment: For me, the problem was I was adding a timeout value.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery uses a `<script>` tag to implement JSONP. You cannot abort the loading of script tags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use some sequencing logic. This will assure your last request prevails over the old ones.
Here you have an [example](http://live.julik.nl/2011/07/ajax-sequencing).

Also, you can take advantage of these `$.ajax` settings:

`timeout:` set a time limit per request and prevent requests fail silently.

`beforeSend:` validate some conditions before making the call. Complements sequencing helper.

```
As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.
```

Example:

```
function updateResults() {

  // Init counter & record current request
  if (!window.reqSeq)  window.reqSeq = 0;
  window.reqSeq +=1;
  var thisRequest = window.reqSeq;

  $.ajax({
    url: [..],
    crossDomain: true, 
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000, // give 5 seconds of margin
    data: { [..] },
    beforeSend: function() {
      if(thisRequest < window.reqSeq) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if(thisRequest < window.reqSeq) {
        return;
      }
      else print(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // it'll be called on timeout (error) and beforeSend (abort)
      print(textStatus);
    }
  });

}
```