# Uncaught TypeError with select2 and remote jsonp dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, geonames

I'm trying to query the Geonames data with select2 and everything appears to be working with formatting the results. However, an error is generated when the results are populated and I believe it is stopping the formatSelection function from not being executed.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6CVbw/

The error being generated is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery18206926385117694736_1350159499559' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: This happens in Chrome and Safari, try searching for London or Toronto.

Comment: I'm not seeing that error in your fiddle at all, when does it occur?

Comment: As soon as you enter a query and the results are displayed.

Comment: Totally not getting that error, the only errors in the console are images that didn't load, no issue there. What browser are you using?

Comment: Happens in chrome and safari. Searching for Toronto on London displays those errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is inside select2 plugin. If be more accurate - in JSONP loading based on jQuery.
As I see in your unpacked code here: http://jsfiddle.net/6CVbw/1/

You can comment this line:

```
//null !== d && d.abort();
```

And the problem is gone. It's caused by aborting JSONP requests.
You can't abort JSONP calls - because you can't abort loading of script tags (JSONP technique).

More details covered here:
[Aborting jQuery JSONP request will throw error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533848/aborting-jquery-jsonp-request-will-throw-error)

You can make proxy script on your backend and request simple JSON, then `.abort()` should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks! It does fix the Uncaught TypeError, but still will not select a result correctly. That's a different issue though.

Comment: That explains why I only seemed to see it depending on how fast I was typing, interesting.